# jquery scroll to with toggle

Tags: jquery, scroll, toggle

I'm looking to add scroll to function on click event. If click on button scroll down then scroll up.

So far I have this but need to scroll up on `click $('#review-link').click(function(e) { });`

```
function scrollToAnchor(anchor){
  var aTag = $("#new_comment");
    $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: aTag.offset().top},'slow');
  }

$("#review-link").click(function() {
  scrollToAnchor('#new_comment');
});
```

Thanks. Also any way to avoid having href="#" in the url?

Comment: could you post it on jsfiddle or post at least your html code? thank you.

Comment: Here you go http://jsfiddle.net/qVGVR/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I remade the complete code, Take a look here

```
function scrollToAnchor(anchor){
  var aTag = $(anchor);
    // you want to scroll to something that doesnt exist anymore when you 
    // toggle it out, makes no sense
    // alert(aTag.offset().top);
    $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: aTag.offset().top},'slow');
  }

$('#review-link').click(function(e) {
    $('.new_comment').toggle();
    // $('.comments').toggle();
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
    if($(this).hasClass('active')){

       $(this).text('Exit review mode');
       scrollToAnchor('.comments');
       return false;

    }else{

        $(this).text('Enter review mode');
        $('body').animate({scrollTop: 0},'slow');
        return false;
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tAQYf/2/

Comment: Thanks, this is helping. Meanwhile I've updated code. Please have a look http://jsfiddle.net/qVGVR/

Comment: I don't get it where you want to scroll to ? Make perhaps an example with more elements..

Comment: Thanks @johnny000 - in your sample, under first scroll I want to scroll down to comments div. One else condition I want it to scroll to the top

Comment: You have a big issue on the way you think. You want to scroll to something that you toggle out just a command before

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I need (I will adjust it to fix the scrolling toggle issue you mention).

Comment: Hi Johnny, in my app with the same code I'm getting 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'aTag.offset().top') when I click on link. Any idea?

Comment: 1:1 the same code or did you change anything, like selectors etc, post code if you can please

Comment: For me it's working, in your fiddle you have a url in the javascript in front of the function. Here the clean version http://jsfiddle.net/tAQYf/5/

Comment: I think my problem is it doesn't preventDefault properly in my app. When I click the link it triggers url.com/# and raising error in browser but working still

Comment: hm it's hard to tell what the issue could be without seeing the app

Comment: Yep. ok I'm down to the scrollToAnchor function causing the issue. Any idea to refactor (scrolltoview or something)? Basically on click in I need to scroll down. We can drop scroll up on toggle out. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Use [scrolIntoView](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.scrollIntoView) Javascript function